# How does OCaml manage Garbage Collection for native code?

Tags: ocaml

I am not a expert in GC, but I always image that GC need a *VM* to work, am I right?

If I am right, then how native code get GC?

Comment: See http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~lukstafi/pmwiki/uploads/Functional/functional-lecture09.pdf pages 18-22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not need a VM to do garbage collection. So this leaves us with no question to answer :-)

Generally speaking, to do GC you just need to track various details of your program state. In particular you need to know where live values (objects that the program cares about) are located.

Comment: ah, ok, so this gc tracking code is actually like a wrapper and compiled together to native code?

Comment: Very commonly the tracking is handled by a (clever) data structure associated with every call site. The GC code unravels the stack to determine all active call sites, looks at the data structures. But there are many ways to do GC and I am no expert (an understatement).

Answer (score 1):

Ocaml maintains two different heaps; one for Ocaml data and one for malloc'ed C data.  If you return values from C FFI functions, (generally of an abstract type, represented by smart pointers into the C heap) those values are tracked by the ocaml garbage collector.  When the GC notices that the data is unreachable, it will call an associated finalization function via the smart pointer.  Thus it is possible to have the C interface run malloc when an object is created, and free when it is garbage collected.

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual033.html

Comment: My question is actually that how GC is embedded to the native code? for example, my code is just `let x = 1;;`, then in the native code, where is the GC part?

Comment: GC is like a library that treats the program as data. GC is not part of the program itself. It sits off to the side and watches. The compiled program just needs to follow memory layout conventions and provide a way to find the live data.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I got confused. So GC is part of the os?

Comment: I got confused too :) I thought you were asking about how the ocaml GC handles the C heap when using the FFI.

Comment: GC is a generally useful technique that can be used anywhere objects are created and destroyed. In the OCaml context, it's part of the language "runtime", not the OS. As a side comment, these are not the sorts of specific questions StackOverflow is good at. I'd recommend a basic textbook in language implementation, maybe [Lisp in Small Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces)? (I don't know this book but it sounds good.)